GFCI issue, no power or reset
I have a GFCI in bathroom that feeds the other bath with normal receptacle. It worked fine until one day it tripped and will not reset. I have replaced the GFCI and nothing, no green light nor will it reset. I have made sure it is wired properly. When I test the wires I am getting 58V white to black, black to ground is 120V and white to ground is 0V.

First of all, any time you are trouble-shooting or replacing a GFCI, it is extremely important to test with only the "line"/"incoming" wires first. Most GFCI/receptacle devices actually come from the factory with the terminals for "load"/"outgoing" covered with tape. In fact, trouble-shooting for a problem GFCI that has something connected to "load" should start with:

Turn off the breaker
Disconnect the "load" wires
Turn on the breaker
See if it works now

If that works then the problem is in the "load" wires (unlikely, but possible in some cases) or in the receptacles or other devices connected to "load".
Assuming that has been ruled out:
Bad Neutral...Somewhere
For voltage you should have ~ 120V hot (black) to neutral (white), 120V hot to ground (bare/green wire or metal box), 0V neutral ground.
In addition, you should check resistance between neutral and ground, and that should be very low. Why check resistance? Sometimes it can provide a clue. In particular, 0V between two wires can mean they are at the same potential, which is the way neutral and ground should be in a properly wired US system. But it can also mean they simply aren't connected at all! If you check resistance then you can find out what is actually going on. If there is high resistance then there is a loose, almost broken, connection somewhere. If there is infinite resistance then the neutral is broken altogether.
The next step is to determine whether this is affecting all circuits or just this one circuit. Check a few other circuits for hot/neutral, hot/ground and neutral/ground voltage and for neutral/ground resistance. If they check out OK (120V, 120V, 0V, close to 0 Ohms) then the problem is this circuit. If some of them have problems then you may have a bad neutral coming into the house. To really make sure, if you have any 240V/120V receptacles, such as, ideally, a 4-prong dryer receptacle, check the voltages and resistance there.
If you have problems "everywhere" and especially if you find that voltages seem to vary (sometimes < 120V, sometimes > 120V) then call your utility to check for a lost neutral. That is an extremely serious situation which can cause all sorts of problems with electric devices in your house. Most of the time a whole-house lost neutral is a utility problem rather than a problem in your panel.
However, if other circuits are fine then you need to check every junction box, receptacle, light fixture, etc. on this circuit. Bathrooms are supposed to have dedicated circuits but in older houses (like mine) the bathroom circuit often includes lights and/or receptacles throughout the house. A bad neutral connection at any place on the circuit before the wires get to the bathroom can cause this type of strange problem.
Look for:

Signs of burning or melting
Wires (particularly white wires) that are not connected to anything
Loose wire nuts
Loose wires on screws
Wires in "backstab" connections instead of screws

and fix any problems you find. After that, if you still have problems then some more very specific trouble-shooting may be needed.

My home is 5 years old. This bath GFI and the receptacle in the other bath are the only ones on the circuit, no light switches. I’ve done the checks for loose wires on receptacle and GFI and all seem good. No other issues electrically in the home, just this.
Appreciate the help and as Clint Eastwood once said, “a man gotta know his limitations”. I’ll be calling in a pro and watching!

Yeah, a 5-year-old home should definitely have circuit(s) dedicated to bathroom(s). Still a possibility of another junction box somewhere. And of course a possibility of a bad connection in the panel - but that is something that many people would be much more reluctant to touch. I was my electrician's helper when he replaced my panels (3 old to 1 new) a couple of years ago - lots of fun!

58 VAC on white wire implies a bad neutral. Either it is completely open, and the voltage is being picked up through capacitance, or the neutral wire is broken at the entrance, and voltage is being divided unevenly.
In either case, this situation is both an electric shock and a fire hazard. This requires repair by a qualified electrician and/or the local electric utility, particularly if the break is outside the house.

Breaker box is in the garage. I have the box thrown at the box since it went out. Just for my benefit, broken at the entrance would mean neutral wire broken at the breaker side or the GFI side?

By "at the entrance", I meant to include the wires from the mains transformer on a power pole or underground, all the way to the house. On multiple occasions, we've had branches fall on that wire, breaking only the more-fragile aluminum neutral. If some of the lamps in the house are over-bright, and others dim, it's one indication of broken neutral (though LED lamps may compensate for that voltage change).
